# Losing ssl when on some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I am using `rails 4.2.2`, deploying to production on Heroku and using the free level of Cloudflare for ssl. In my production.rb file I have set

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

If I am not signed in as a user, then ssl works and I see the padlock in the browser url bar, and I see it for all unsigned-in pages. However, once I log into the site, the padlock disappears on all signed-in pages. When I am signed in and chose a different signed-in page, the padlock temporarily appears as the page is being loaded but then disappears when the loading is complete.  All this happens on both Chrome and Safari.  I am not using Devise.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using devise ?

Comment: I am not using Devise. I have now included this fact in the question.

Comment: Are the logs telling you anything ? Can you click and inspect the padlock for info? Did you miss a cloudlflare configuration? http://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/integrations/cloudflare/#confirm-ssl, do you use a cdn or host your assets on the same server ?

Comment: In regard to Laurens's comment. The logs do not show anything relevant.  The padlock, when it appears, has the correct information.  I looked at the docs and can see nothing wrong with my configuration. I am not using a cdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the support team at [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com), I was able to solve this.

The signed in users can use a gravatar, but the gravatar_image_tag was not being used with the secure setting. This meant the image was being transferred using http not https.  This could be seen by looking at the developer console, which was displaying an error indicating the page was displaying with mixed http and https. In order to fix this problem, I just used the secure setting for the gravatar_image_tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devise, take a look at this:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-SSL-(HTTPS)

Comment: I am not using Devise. I have now included this fact in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the page accesses to some in-secure asserts (ex: images in AWS S3). Chrome Developer Console shows that the page is mixed-secured. Change S3 image links from http to https make ssl works.